# Adxstudio ver 7.0.0023, An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

Tags: dynamics-crm, adxstudio-portals

After I upgraded to Adxstudio from 7.0.0022 to 7.0.0023, I got the following error when doing global searches. I was running the site locally from an IIS express. I have updated all CRM solutions and dll libraries. Have any of you had this problem also before? Any known fixes? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue with adx 7.0.0023 deployed in azure (7.0.0022 worked fine)- resolved by switching platform for the web app in azure from 32bit to 64bit..